# Как спрятать скрипт пайтон

Tags: python

Всем привет написал программу, шифр к ней, однако мне нужно спрятать скрипт расшифровщик, так чтобы пользователь не увидел, а .dll мог запустить

Comment: Это невозможно. Если кто-то сможет расшифровать и запустить скрипт, значит пользователь тоже сможет.

Comment: @andreymal мне необходимо сделать чтобюы его хотябы было трудно прочитать

Comment: Тогда достаточно просто в *.pyc скомпилировать, прочитать его уже достаточно трудно для большинства (но специалисты что угодно прочитают в любом случае)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо вам большое. запишите это как ответ. я дам вам награду. 100 балов репутации

Comment: Слава богу, что еще есть способные люди, которым нечего прятать.

Answer (score 4):

Спрятать файл так, чтобы его нельзя было найти - невозможно. Если кто-то захочет его найти - всегда будет путь чтобы это сделать. Из вариантов - только сделать свою ОС которая не будет позволять программам читать этот файл. И то не факт, что пользователь не найдёт лазейку в ОС или вообще её не перепишет как душе угодно. Вы можете зашифровать скрипт. Например использовать rar или сделать вообще свой шифровщик. Например зашифровать скрипт, а в dll будет шифровщик который его расшифрует. Но это опять не факт, что сработает. Никто не мешает пользователю пытаться дизассемблировать dll и пытаться понять, как работает шифровщик. Или вовсе просто использовать этот же dll чтобы расшифровать скрипт. Это можно обойти используя ключ. Тогда если пользователь поймёт принцип работы шифровщика - он не сможет ничего сделать с файлом. Но это позволит ему просто его взломать подобрав ключ. В этом случае вы можете сделать шифр так - каждый символ скрипта будет, например, 1024 символами. С помощью ключа вы случайно генерируете алфавит, где каждый символ имеет 1024 значение и так расшифровываете его. И шифруете тоже. Можно сделать случайное количество символов для 1 символа. Например в таком радиусе - 1024-2048. Всё это будет случайно генерироваться от hash ключа. Всё ещё будет возможно подобрать ключ, но это будет очень ОЧЕНЬ долго.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать создать rar архив с паролем{Сложным}, а dll который его откроет собрать в exe
но exe отметится как вирус, так как будет лазить в вашей файловой системе, потом ещё и скрипт запустит

Comment: Пароль нужно будет где-то хранить, а значит пользователь сможет увидеть пароль в том месте, в котором он хранится

Comment: Да и момент распаковки наверняка можно будет отследить и спокойно взять распакованный файл

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы для большинства людей было очень трудно расшифровать Ваш файл .py можете скомпилировать его в .pyc файл. Или вообще преобразовать программу на Python в машинный код с помощью библиотеки Pyinstaller.

Comment: Однако специалисты смогут расшифровать Ваш файл.

Comment: pyinstaller ничего ни во что не «преобразовывает». почитайте описание. оно не секретное. https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html

Answer (score -2):

В принципе на windows 10 можно прятать файлы  [image: такой не хитрой галочкой в свойствах файла]
однако пользователь увидит файл если у него в проводнике включен параметр показывать скрытые файлы, я всё же рекомендую сделать сложный файловый путь, а файл скрыть где-то в нём

Comment: в принципе так сделать можно, но есть ли ещё способы спрятать файл?

Comment: Пользователю ничто не помешает проанализировать все сложные файловые пути, если он захочет